# unable to manipulate DOM elements of external HTML loaded by AJAX load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asynchronous

I have following HTMl in index.php

```
<div id="internal" class="internal-class"></div>
<a href="external.php #external-element" class="button">Load</a>
```

And CSS like this

```
#internal {
    padding: 50px;
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
}
#external-element {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

And I have one external php page external.php like this

```
<div id="external-element" class="external-class"></div>
```

I have used the following script in index.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(event){
        $attrib = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#internal').load($attrib,function(){
            alert($('#internal').attr('class'));
            alert($('.external-element').attr('class'));

        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

In the above code the jQuery script successfully loads the `#external-element` from external.php in the div `#internal`. And after loading I wanted to alert classes of both `#internal` as well as `#external-element`.

```
$('#internal').load($attrib,function(){

    alert($('#internal').attr('class'));
    alert($('.external-element').attr('class'));

});
```

above code successfully alerts the name of class of `#internal` & `#external-element`.
But when I write

```
$('#internal').load($attrib);
    alert($('#internal').attr('class'));
    alert($('#external-element').attr('class'));
```

then above code is not alerting the class of `#external-element`. It is saying `undefined`.

I think, it is unable to manipulate DOM of external.php after AJAX `load()`.

Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
$('#internal').load($attrib,function(){
        alert($('#internal').attr('class'));
        alert($('.external-element').attr('class'));
});
```

It is successfully alerting because the asynchronous callback function inside `load` is called when `load` is completed (i. e. when the elements are loaded).

When you do:

```
$('#internal').load($attrib);
alert($('#internal').attr('class'));
alert($('#external-element').attr('class'));
```

The `load` call has not necessarily completed when the alerts are called.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `.load` is async. When you run the `alert` in your failed attempt the content is still being loaded into `#internal` - hence why you need to use the callback function just like your first example.